# Regex: Replace '&amp;' within double quotes

Tags: javascript, regex

I have this strange issue where URL parameter divider `&` of an `IMG SRC` gets replaced with the HTML entity.

**I need to replace those so this string:**

`<img src="https://example.com/imagehandler?$PNG%20with%20alpha$&amp;scl=1" alt="">`

**Returns:**

`<img src="https://example.com/imagehandler?$PNG%20with%20alpha$&scl=1" alt="">`

It should only replace within double quotes — not if in other places like regular HTML entities.

Comment: Why do you need that? You're asking to make valid HTML invalid.

Comment: I'm not... :) The url-parameter of the IMG is invalid... I think you misunderstood something.

Comment: Tried anything?

Comment: @KennethB — No. `&` means "Start of character reference" in HTML. If you want to express an ampersand in HTML you should use the character reference for it, which is `&amp;`. The HTML you started with is absolutely fine.

Comment: What am I missing? According to [HTML validators](http://htmlhelp.com/tools/validator/direct.html.en), your desired outcome triggers "Error: unknown entity scl". That doesn't mean that `&amp;` becomes the actual URL value, it's just the way to encode it inside HTML.

Comment: I tried researching for a solution for replacing a string within quotes and double quotes, but I couldn't find anything.

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález: The first image tag contains only 1 url parameter, because the last divider is converted to HTML entity &amp;... I want to replace that wrong HTML entity to "&", so that the image now has 2 url parameters.

Comment: Sorry, I can't make myself understood. When you type `console.log('O\'Brian');` you get `O'Brian` without the backslash because the backslash is just a syntax to escape the quote, not part of the actual value. Your case is the same. The manipulation you want to do will not change the actual URL, it will only make the HTML invalid. It will seem to work because browsers are designed to ignore errors.

Comment: I assume he isn't working with this on front-end but a kind of manipulating data which he feel the need. @ÁlvaroGonzález

Comment: @revo Do you mean it's actually a "parse HTML with regular expressions" kind of question?

Comment: Kind of but due requirements, I don't call it parsing. Just a simple find and replace demand. @ÁlvaroGonzález

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### A regex workaround:

```js
var text = `<img src="https://example.com/imagehandler?$PNG%20with%20alpha$&amp;scl=1" alt="">`;
console.log(text.replace(/src="[^"]+/g, function(match) {
  return match.replace('&amp;', '&');
}));
```

### A DOM solution:

According to your statement, *It's a string, not in the dom...*, you should use [`DOMParser`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMParser) to convert a HTML string into valid DOM. Modifying @prasad's answer it would be something like this:

```js
var HTMLmarkup = `
<img src="https://example.com/imagehandler?$PNG%20with%20alpha$&amp;scl=1" alt="">
<img src="https://example.com/imagehandler?$PNG%20with%20alpha$&amp;scl=1" alt="">
`
var parser = new DOMParser()
var dom = parser.parseFromString(HTMLmarkup, "text/html");
dom.querySelectorAll('img').forEach(function(a){
  console.log(a.src)
})
```

Comment: Yeah! Thanks! :)

Comment: `a.src.replace('&amp;','&')` does nothing. Parsing the HTML into a DOM will decode the HTML entities. The `src` property contains text, not HTML.

Answer (score 1):

Try with simple regex pattern `/&amp;/g` .And [**querySelectorAll**](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwjfzJieqZzUAhULPI8KHY_MChgQFggvMAE&url=https%3A%2F%2Fdeveloper.mozilla.org%2Fen-US%2Fdocs%2FWeb%2FAPI%2FElement%2FquerySelectorAll&usg=AFQjCNFBcHY35qskrceNmsOdFxfGiSZauQ&sig2=qiLT5HxkAALM9M5jQcmF1Q) used for select the `img` element

[**Demo regex**](https://regex101.com/r/zIghBM/1/)

```js
document.querySelectorAll('img').forEach(function(a){
a.src = a.src.replace(/&amp;/g,"")
console.log(a.src)
})
```

```html
<img src="https://example.com/imagehandler?$PNG%20with%20alpha$&amp;scl=1" alt="">
```

Comment: It's a string, not in the dom... But I guess I could make a workaround. Thanks for the idea! :-)

Comment: That won't do anything. The `src` property will be a string of text, not a string of HTML. The character reference will already have been decoded to a plain `&`. Remove the regex line and you'll get exactly the same result.

Comment: But you are post with in `Img` tag .That why i was use with dom

Comment: Sure, not a problem... My mistake in under informing... but I can work around that... Thanks again.

Comment: @KennethB Use [`DOMParser`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMParser)

Comment: Thanks. But that's not what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 0):

For completeness, here's a solution that uses regular DOM functions. It diverges from the original requirement in that it extracts the URL because (IMHO) it's a reasonable ultimate goal:

```js
var html = '<img src="https://example.com/imagehandler?$PNG%20with%20alpha$&amp;scl=1" alt=""> <img src="/some/other/location/?one=1&amp;two=2&amp;three=3">';
var aux = document.createElement("div");
aux.innerHTML = html;

var urls = [];
aux.querySelectorAll("img[src]").forEach(function(image){
    urls.push(image.getAttribute("src"));
});
console.log(urls);
```